# Change Material React Table padding

Tags: reactjs, datatable, material-ui

So i have material react table component, but i notice one things that the padding of the header suddenly have padding-left 3rem, which i cannot find where the style is located and causing the alignment to be not centered, i try to override it using material ui styling but still the same, here is what i means:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
const tableTheme = useMemo(
    () =>
      createTheme({
        palette: {
          mode: globalTheme.palette.mode, //let's use the same dark/light mode as the global theme
          primary: globalTheme.palette.secondary, //swap in the secondary color as the primary for the table
          info: {
            main: "rgb(255,122,0)", //add in a custom color for the toolbar alert background stuff
          },
          background: {
            default:
              globalTheme.palette.mode === "light"
                ? "rgb(235,236,236)" //random light yellow color for the background in light mode
                : "#000", //pure black table in dark mode for fun
          },
        },
        typography: {
          button: {
            textTransform: "none", //customize typography styles for all buttons in table by default
            fontSize: "1.2rem",
          },
        },

        components: {
          MuiTooltip: {
            styleOverrides: {
              tooltip: {
                fontSize: "1.1rem", //override to make tooltip font size larger
              },
            },
          },
          MuiSwitch: {
            styleOverrides: {
              thumb: {
                color: "red", //change the color of the switch thumb in the columns show/hide menu to pink
              },
            },
          },
        },
      }),
    [globalTheme]
  );

  //columns Header
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        id: "data",
        muiTableHeadCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
        muiTableBodyCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
        header: "Details",
        columns: [
          {
            accessorKey: "material",
            size: 50,
            header: "Material",
            muiTableHeadCellProps: {
              align: "center",
            },
            muiTableBodyCellProps: {
              align: "center",
            },
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "material_name",
            header: "Material Name",
            muiTableHeadCellProps: {
              align: "center",
            },
            muiTableBodyCellProps: {
              align: "center",
            },
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "plant",
            header: "Plant",
            muiTableHeadCellProps: {
              align: "center",
            },
            muiTableBodyCellProps: {
              align: "center",
            },
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "type",
            header: "Type",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            muiTableHeadCellProps: {
              align: "center",
            },
            muiTableBodyCellProps: {
              align: "center",
            },
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "current_price",
            header: "Current Price",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
        ],
      },

      {
        id: "grouped",
        muiTableHeadCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
        muiTableBodyCellProps: {
          align: "center",
        },
        header: "Price ",
        columns: [
          {
            accessorKey: "januari",
            header: "Januari",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "februari",
            header: "Februari",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "maret",
            header: "Maret",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "april",
            header: "April",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "mei",
            header: "Mei",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "juni",
            header: "Juni",

            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "juli",
            header: "Juli",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "agustus",
            header: "Agustus",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "september",
            header: "September",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "oktober",
            header: "Oktober",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "november",
            header: "November",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            accessorKey: "desember",
            header: "Desember",
            enableColumnActions: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            Cell: ({ cell }) => (
              <>
                {cell.getValue()?.toLocaleString?.("en-US", {
                  style: "currency",
                  currency: "IDR",
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </>
            ),
          },
        ],
      },
      //column definitions...
    ],
    []
  );


return (
    <div className="bg-white">
      <div className="text-left pl-2 pb-2 font-bold text-3xl">
        <h2>Master Data Material</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="bg-white ml-1">
        <Box sx={{ width: "100%", typography: "body1" }}>
          <TabContext
            TabIndicatorProps={{ style: { background: "#FF0000" } }}
            value={value}
            index={0}
            classes={{ root: useStyles.tab }}
          >
            <Box sx={{ borderColor: "divider", p: 0 }}>
              <TabList
                index={0}
                classes={{}}
                onChange={handleChange}
                TabIndicatorProps={{ style: { background: "#FF0000" } }}
                variant="scrollable"
                scrollButtons="auto"
                aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
              >
                <Tab
                  label="Material Data All"
                  value="1"
                  style={{ color: "#FF0000" }}
                />
                <Tab
                  label="Material Data"
                  value="2"
                  style={{ color: "#FF0000" }}
                />
              </TabList>
            </Box>
            <TabPanel style={{ padding: 2 }} value="1">
              <div className="m-2 rounded-t-md">
                <ThemeProvider theme={tableTheme}>
                  <MaterialReactTable
                    columns={columns}
                    data={transformed}
                    enableColumnFilters={false}
                    enableDensityToggle={false}
                    enableStickyHeader
                    enableGlobalFilterModes
                    initialState={{
                      showGlobalFilter: true,
                    }}
                    positionGlobalFilter="left"
                    muiSearchTextFieldProps={{
                      placeholder: `Search data`,
                      sx: { minWidth: "100px", minHeight: "10px" },
                    }}
                    editingMode="modal" //default
                    enableColumnOrdering
                    enableEditing
                    onEditingRowSave={handleSaveRow}
                    onEditingRowCancel={(e) => console.log(e)}
                    renderRowActions={({ exitEditingMode, row, table }) => (
                      <Box sx={{ display: "flex", gap: "1rem" }}>
                        <Tooltip arrow placement="left" title="Edit">
                          <IconButton
                            onClick={() =>
                              console.log(
                                row.getValue("material"),
                                row.getValue("plant")
                              )
                            }
                          >
                            <Edit />
                          </IconButton>
                        </Tooltip>
                        <Tooltip arrow placement="right" title="Delete">
                          <IconButton
                            color="error"
                            onClick={() =>
                              console.log(
                                row.getValue("material"),
                                row.getValue("plant")
                              )
                            }
                          >
                            <Delete />
                          </IconButton>
                        </Tooltip>
                      </Box>
                    )}
                    muiTableContainerProps={{
                      sx: { maxHeight: "500px", margin: "1px" },
                    }}
                    getRowId={(row) => row.id}
                    manualPagination
                    muiTableHeadCellProps={{
                      align: "center",
                      sx: {
                        borderRight: "2px solid #e0e0e0",
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                        borderTop: "2px solid #e0e0e0",
                        margin: "2px",
                      },
                    }}
                    muiTableBodyCellProps={{
                      align: "center",
                      sx: {
                        borderRight: "2px solid #e0e0e0",
                        borderTop: "2px solid #e0e0e0",
                        margin: "2px",
                      },
                    }}
                    manualSorting
                    muiToolbarAlertBannerProps={
                      isError
                        ? {
                            color: "error",
                            children: "Error loading data, No data found",
                          }
                        : undefined
                    }
                    onGlobalFilterChange={setGlobalFilter}
                    onPaginationChange={setPagination}
                    onSortingChange={setSorting}
                    rowCount={rowCount}
                    state={{
                      globalFilter,
                      isLoading,
                      density: "compact",
                      pagination,
                      showAlertBanner: isError,
                      showProgressBars: isRefetching,
                      sorting,
                    }}
                    muiTableBodyProps={{
                      sx: {
                        //stripe the rows, make odd rows a darker color
                        "& td:nth-of-type(odd)": {
                          backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
                        },
                        margin: "2px",
                        padding: "2px",
                      },
                    }}
                  />
                </ThemeProvider>
              </div>
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel style={{ padding: 2 }} value="2"></TabPanel>
          </TabContext>
        </Box>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

I seek for answer on documentation and the storybook example but still not giving me any answer to that, anyone here that understand Materialreacttable and can give me an explanation or any sugestion to override it?

Answer (score 2):

Done, by adding a little modification on the code i finally solved it, hards to find the actually classname by tracking it here is the code, hope can help u all:

```
muiTableHeadCellProps={{
              sx: {
                borderRight: " solid #e0e0e0",
                alignItems: "center",
                "& .Mui-TableHeadCell-Content-Labels": {
                  padding: "0px",
                },
                "& .MuiBox-root": {
                  padding: "0px",
                },
                backgroundColor: "white",

                borderTop: " solid #e0e0e0",
              },
            }}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks. Can you share the docs, where you found this, please?